# iOS background push notifications not received after 2-3 hours of inactivity

Tags: ios, background, notifications, push

My app performs silent background fetch via push notifications. Everything is working fine, and push notifications sent from our server trigger silent background fetches as expected, when the user has opened the app within the last 60 minutes or a push notification has been sent within 60 minutes - even if the device is locked.

However, when the user doesn't open the app for 2-3 hours or when a push notification hasn't been sent in 2-3 hours, the app isn't receiving the push notification. I have been logging app activity, and I've confirmed that:

```
didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:
```

is not being called on the app delegate.

A few more facts:

1. In the app's plist.info, I have set UIRequiresPersistentWiFi to true and UIBackgroundModes to (only) remote-notification
2. The push notification payload contains only the content-available key
3. After 2-3 hours of inactivity (either from no push notification sent or no user activity), I am seeing the same result on both my iPhone 5 and Wifi-only iPad 2, both running iOS 8.1.2. In other words, it doesn't matter whether the internet connection is cellular or Wifi.
4. I don't believe I am hitting rate-limit boundaries, as I am only sending at most 1-2 push notifications per device per hour.

My understanding is that iOS should continue to wake the app up in the background and enable it to process the background fetch from the push notification - even after hours of inactivity (as long as the device is awake and has an internet connection).

I'm wondering if anyone else has experienced this, and if so, if you've found a workaround.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: We have a similar problem. If I send "content-available":1 notification after a longer period of inactivity, it is ignored. However if I send a "regular" notification it appears on the phone. I can't really find a pattern, since for example I left 2 phones overnight, and one of them responded, and the other didn't. Did you manage to find any further leads to the problem?

Comment: Did you every find a solution for this? I am having the same issue...

Comment: @Jacob, did you tried to send a payload with empty "sound" key? this usually works

Comment: @Sega-Zero I sent "" for the sound key, yes.

Comment: try to sent a payload with 0 badge (or the number that was set previously) and then content-avaliable. Hope that will force payload to be sent to an app.

Comment: @Sega-Zero thanks for the reply. I am using parse.com for my push service and I am seeing that the push is being sent to the correct number of devices, but the method is not called on the receiving end after some idle time as the OP stated. If this helps, I know that the receiving device will have the app open all the time, so it is always in the foreground.

Comment: @Sega-Zero sometimes the notification will get delivered 5-15 minutes late, but Apple only holds the most recent one in the cache, so if I send any more in that time period the original is lost.

Comment: @Jacob, well, then maybe apple thinks the device is offline and caching the last payload? [Docs says](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW4) that QoS component holds the last payload for a limited period of time.

maybe you could call some url when receiving a push in `didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:` to make sure the device did received it and if not, try to repeat payload sending?

Comment: @Sega-Zero well that's the thing, after some period of time that method isn't called, so my log statements don't log, and I won't be able to call a url. Like the OP, I thought that the push should wake the device up to receive the push as it is clearly online with a strong internet connection. It only caches sometimes, after the few hours of inactivity.

Comment: @Jacob, that must be the case just for the silent push notifications, i think. because the ones with text definitely wakes the device up.

Comment: @Sega-Zero I am sending text in the "alert" field of the payload. Should I not be doing this?

Comment: @Jacob, so you're facing with push notifications loss with alert field included? That's pretty weird, it was always working on my projects. Well, as a last guess, maybe setting a higher priority to payload sending helps? `priority: 5` or maybe even `priority: 10`

Comment: @Sega-Zero can I send that directly in the payload? I have another question here that is related http://stackoverflow.com/q/30411590/2584268 I thought the payload was separate from the priority?

Comment: @Jacon, no, priority is not part of payload, it's part of the send packet. See [Notification Format](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/CommunicatingWIthAPS.html)

Comment: @Sega-Zero I do not know how to set the priority of a push notification sent through parse.com as it is not outlined in their docs.

Comment: @Jacob, it doesn't seem to have such an option. Plus, i've found 2 weird things:


1.
 > When using content-available to send silent push notifications, keep in mind that APNS may throttle push notifications sent to the same device token within a short period of time.


2. [this topic](https://www.parse.com/questions/remote-notifications-with-content-available-1)

it seems like content-available payloads are sent via parse.com with lowest priority and you should ask to solve your problem on parse.com forums

Comment: @Sega-Zero Thanks, I will keep that in mind. Do I need to use the content-available key at all? According to that parse thread, the issue should have been resolved a year ago.

Comment: @Jacob, It depends on your needs. If you need to receive every push notification into app, process it and make some background stuff (like content downloading) - the content-available is the only option. If you just need to display a text to the user - you can remove that key. P.S. I think we should move to a separate thread for discussion...)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78960/discussion-between-jacob-and-sega-zero).

Comment: @Sega-Zero I have removed that key from my payload, as well as the background fetch keys from the info.plist but the pushes still do not deliver after a period of inactivity or idleness. I do not know why the service thinks the device is offline as it is clearly opened and connected to the internet. Any other ideas?

Comment: @Jacob, Make sure this is not a parse.com issue, try to send a payload manually via [NWPusher](https://github.com/noodlewerk/NWPusher) for example. If nothing changes, you probably better to ask on developer forums or even open a TSI.

Comment: @Sega-Zero Parse does not handle the delivery of the notification to the device, they handle the delivery to APNs, and their data browser says all of mine have been delivered correctly.

Answer (score 1):

go through

Targets > Capabilities > Background Modes

Turn on Background Modes

Answer (score 0):

There is no work-around as such. You can try `PushKit` (iOS VOIP push notifications), which are more reliable but iOS8 only or VOIP persistent socket, which is available from iOS7 (much more difficult).

Apple does not guarantee immediate delivery for background / fetch push notifications (containing: `content-available=1`). 
Those notifications were designed to give app `a chance` to update its content in between runs, not to be '`immediate`' nor reliable.

iOS will decide when to deliver this notifications based on undocumented, energy related conditions.

In other words - your app will be notified, only when iOS decides, it does not affect the battery. From my observations, it depends on many things, like:

- if your device is connected to power source,
- uses Wi-Fi of 3G,
- time from last notification,
- energy and data bandwidth app used when processing last one, itd...
- when and how was device used in recent past (locked / unlocked screen)

I even noticed the difference between app running in debug session (by Xcode, connected by cable) - notifications were always delivered, and when I started app from Springboard / in release mode (different energy conditions) - then it started misbehaving.

Comment: What if I have removed the content-available key from my payload? I am still having issues after the app has been idle. It just seems so random. I can never remember not receiving notifications on my phone, now it's happening all the time on the iPad.

Comment: When you remove content-available flag, delegate method will NEVER be called when app is in the background by itself. You will only see banner in the notification center and you need to tap on it (interact with) to invoke the callback.

Comment: The app is always in the foreground-always. That is why I don't understand the discrepancies because the method should always be called.

Comment: @Jacob I am a bit confused since you wrote you are having issues after app 'has been idle' and then that it is 'always in the foreground'. The fact that app is in the foreground does not mean it is in active state. When screen is locked (after dimming away) - app goes into inactive state. Is this what you meant by 'idle'?

Comment: I have the idle timer of my app set to not dim the screen at all. So the receiving iPad app is always open and in the foreground, and the screen does not dim or lock at any point.

Comment: In this case - every push notification (with or without content-available) should invoke didReveiveRemoteNotificaiton:.... app delegate callback.

Comment: That's what I thought...but that method is not always called. :/

Comment: Any ideas as to why this is happening? Does Apple think the device is offline for some reason? Could it have to do with the number of pushes being sent within a certain timeframe?

Answer (score 0):

```
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
```

Comment: Can you comment about what this code actually does rather than just posting it as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your info.plist it worked for me.

[image: info plist file.]

This will awake your app to receive notification in background mode.