# iOS Push Notification Priority

Tags: ios, parse-platform, push-notification

I have push notifications set up and working correctly, however, sometimes I experience delays in the delivery on the end device. Is there a way I can set the "priority" key of the push to be 10 so the push is sent immediately? I don't believe I can just put it in the dictionary with the other keys such as "alert" because Apple's docs say it should be separate from the payload.

Answer (score 1):

You should set `apns-priority` in your request header,
here's [the APNs Provider API doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CommunicatingwithAPNs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH11-SW1).